# Fluent Validation cant use WithLocalizedName

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have this validator:

```
RuleFor(x => x.CardNumber).NotEmpty()
.CreditCard().WithLocalizedMessage(
    () => AppContext.FieldTranslationsContainer.Current.CardNumber.ErrorMessage);
```

`WithLocalizedMessage` throws exception at runtime.

`Could not find a property named 'ErrorMessage' on type 'IBorker.Commons.Configurables.FieldTranslation'.`

This is the member: `CardNumber`

```
public FieldTranslation CardNumber { get; set; }
```

this is the class:

```
public class FieldTranslation
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Helper { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have to set your resource file access modifier to "Public".
To do that:

1. Open your resource file.
2. Look for "Access Modifier" drop down on right the top
3. Set it to Public